# Primary key advice for simple table

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm making a sample database to test myself in MySQL workbench and was wondering the following:

I have five tables, Customer, Product, Stock(Quantity), Warehouse and Purchase Order.

For primary keys I have customerId, productId, warehouseId, and invoiceNo...but what would the stocks primary key be? Apologies if the answer is obvious, but as I understand it the foreign key would be the productNo.

Very new to this!

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: is there a 1 to one relationship between a product and a stock? If so why it a different table?

Comment: hi dan, it was a different table just to make it a bit more complex, for the learning process, 1 to 1 yes, If I'm correct in saying that means every one product has one stock attribute and vice versa?

Comment: these are my attributes for this example if it helps: CUSTOMER: customerNo, firstName, lastName, emailAddress, phoneNumber 
PRODUCT: productCode, name, description, price 
ORDER: orderID, customerNo, productCode, comment
STOCK: productCode, warehouseCode quantity
WAREHOUSE: warehouseCode, phoneNumber, address

Comment: Putting addition information in the question (especially when large) is usually desirable. `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}` also recommended for readability. Welcome to DBA.

Comment: Thanks very much, would you mind if I asked one further question? I said id start light with three tables, customers, purchase order and product... If for example, a customer can have many orders, but an order can only be placed by one customer, are those multiplicities 1.* and 0.1 respectively? I'll assume for the sake of this example that my order and product are many to many.

Comment: I'd think customer -> order is `0.*` as they don't have to have an order. By `1.1` on order side as it has to have a customer. My db theory of teams has got really weak since I've been more practical so errors may be in this statement.

Comment: Step 1 in deciding on the `PRIMARY KEY` for a table is writing the main `SELECTs` that will touch the table.  Show me the `SELECTs` so I can help you.

Comment: There are 3 main types: 1:1, which is usually frowned on.  1:many which needs the id of one being a column in the other.  many:many, which needs an extra table.  0:n is just a degenerate case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given with STOCK the same product could be multiple warehouses, the combined `(productCode, warehouseCode)` is the unique element for this table and that should be the primary key.

Comment: thats great thank you!